# cell address in c#

Tags: c#, cell

I am using 
dsOld.Tables[0].Columns[j]
to get the column data but I want to get the cell address using column in excel using c#.
is there any way to calculate..

Comment: I  think you need to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should navigate rows and check for specified cell index (column index)

```
for(var i = 0; i < dsOld.Tables[0].rows.Count; i++)
   dsOld.Tables[0].rows[i].cells[j]
```